# Is it possible to transform a query joining onto a subselect into JPQL?

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Given the following native SQL query containing a join to a subselect, is there a way to transform it into a JPQL query (or alternatively, is it possible to map this using `@SqlResultSetMapping` such that I don't have to execute thousands of subsequent queries to populate my objects (say in this case, `Foo` contains a reference to a single `Bar` and a list of `Baz` entities):

```
SELECT 
    foo.*, bar.*, baz.*
FROM
    foo
        INNER JOIN
    bar ON foo.bar_id = bar.id
        INNER JOIN
    baz ON bar.baz_id = baz.id
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        bar_id, MAX(some_int) ct
    FROM
        foo
    WHERE
        some_int <= 2
    GROUP BY bar_id) max_id ON max_id.bar_id = foo.bar_id
WHERE
    foo.some_int = max_id.ct;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly with JPQL but you can use Blaze-Persistence on top of Hibernate to do this. See the following example: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#subquery-in-from-clause

I'm assuming a JPA model here for the example. You will need the following CTE entity.

```
@CTE
@Entity
public class MyMaxEntity {
  @Id Integer id;
  Integer someInt;
}
```

This is the query

```
criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Foo.class, "foo")
  .fetch("bar.baz")
  .innerJoinOnSubquery(MyMaxEntity.class, "maxEnt")
    .from(Foo.class, "subFoo")
    .bind("id").select("subFoo.id")
    .bind("value").select("MAX(subFoo.someInt)")
    .where("subFoo.someInt").le(2)
  .end()
    .on("maxEnt.id").eqExpression("foo.bar.id")
  .end()
  .where("foo.someInt").eqExpression("maxEnt.value")
```

Comment: That looks promising, but I can't see how to correctly implement this for my example (or anything close). The subquery examples are a bit contrived in the docs.